# Oracle JDBC Driver 11 Javadoc or Source JAR

Tags: oracle, jar, javadoc

I have downloaded the latest version of JAR files for Oracle JDBC, including the source files and javadoc files. The Maven repository is here:

`https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc11/23.2.0.0/`

I've also read this link here:

`https://www.oracle.com/id/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html`

The main JAR for classes is ok. However the JAR for source files contains no file at all. The JAR for javadoc also contain a limited set of documentation. For example the javadoc for `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` class is not available at all. In fact the javadoc JAR file for hundreds of other classes do not exist at all. I'm more surprised to see that the online javadoc also does not exist.

`https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver.html`

Is it just me or these source files and javadocs are actually not available for public?

Comment: They are not available for public.

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle JDBC drivers are not open-sourced, reason why there is no source JAR or Javadoc specific to oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.